# constructor template specialization gives undefined reference to destructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

when i don't specialize the constructor (but other method instead) everything is fine:

Test.h:

```
struct Type_1 {};
struct Type_2 {};

template<typename Type>
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();

    void print();
}
```

Test.cpp:

```
template<typename Type>
Test<Type>::Test() {}

template<typename Type>
Test<Type>::~Test() {}

template<>
Test<Type_1>::print(){ // Type_1 specific print }

template<>
Test<Type_2>::print(){ // Type_2 specific print }
```

works well, he creates the class as long as the template is Type_1 or Type_2 and calls print() accordingly.

but if i try to specialize the constructor instead, he says "undefined reference to destructor" but the destructor should deduce the argument type automatically right?

Test.cpp changed:

```
template<>
Test<Type_1>::Test(){ // constructor when Type_1 }

template<>
Test<Type_2>::Test(){ // constructor when Type_2 }

template<typename Type>
Test<Type>::~Test(){ // should work for all right? }
```

my question is: if i template specialize a constructor do i have to specialize the destructor as well even if its the same for all? is there another way?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not specialize a single function of a template class, you have to specialize the entire class - likely, in a header.

Comment: @DieterLücking That's wrong. You can explicitly specialize a single member function of a class template. (That technique isn't used often, though.)

Comment: May as well throw in the toolchain you're using in case its relevant.

Comment: @dyp Thanks, learned something.

Comment: You can not put the implementation of a template into the implementation file. Move (at least) the dtor to the header.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with this code (except that putting the definition of class template member functions in a source file can lead to nasty errors). Please post a complete program (including a main) that reproduces the problem, and your toolchain + version.

Comment: thats the thing, it works when i define them in the .cpp even if i specialize some methods. both destructor and constructor work in .cpp. its ONLY when i specialize a ctor that the default dctor needs to be in the header file for some reason.. im using gcc 4.8.2 btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to define a specialized version of any of the member functions. You can do it like this:

```
template<typename Type>
class Test {
public:

    Test();
    ~Test() 
    {
        std::cout << "Default Dtor called." << std::endl;
    }

    void print();
};

//! These should go either in the class declaration or in a separate ipp/inl file.
//! You can put these in a .cpp if you use extern templates, but they might not be
//! supported on your compiler.
//! NOTE: If you use ipp/inl or declare these in the header but still outside the
//! class declaration, be sure to use inline on the member function definitions.
struct Type_1{};
struct Type_2{};

template <>
inline Test<Type_1>::Test()
{
    std::cout << "Type_1 Ctor called" << std::endl;
}

template <>
inline Test<Type_1>::~Test()
{
    std::cout << "Type_1 Dtor called" << std::endl;
}

template <>
inline Test<Type_2>::Test()
{
    std::cout << "Type_2 Ctor called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    {
        Test<Type_1> t1;
    }

    {
        Test<Type_2> t2;
    }
}
```

Output:

Type_1 Ctor called

Type_1 Dtor called

Type_2 Ctor called

Default Dtor called.

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: This doesn't compile in clang or g++ without the `template<>`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013... I suppose it's a bug.

Comment: thanks for the answer, defining the dctor inside the class or inside the .h file made it work. but that begs the question, why does every other template specialization in that class work fine when defined in the .cpp file? also should i always define template methods and classes inside the .h? i've always used the template<typename Type> Test<Type>::Test() {} way of declaring inside the .cpp file and it worked so far (except for the destructor but only when i specialize a ctor, else even the dctor works fine in the .cpp). btw using gcc 4.8.2

Comment: I don't know why the issue appears. I wouldn't have expected an error, but this use case of specializing individual member functions isn't common. Most templates are declared inside the header file and within the class declaration. The second most common (IMO) is to have the interface declared in the header and then have the definitions specified as inlines in an ipp or inl file. Declaring explicit instantiations is the least common in my experience. I'll have to have a look and see if I can reproduce your original error in visual studio 2013.